# how to change the default domain to another newly created domain in sites

Tags: force.com-sites, mydomain, custom-domain

I have created one new domain in which i have to deploy the sites of existing domain...how do i change it to new domain....
i tried hard but no luck..Please refer the screenshot..

can anyone please tell me?

[image]

**The above remark showing the default domain..and now i want to add new domain name over there...**

Comment: Have you found a way? If so, please provide and accept the answer below. If not, please accept my answer and close this question.

Comment: You can try to contact salesforce support .. but as far as documentation goes Willem's answer should be correct.

Comment: You can't change that, but you can set the custom web address field (in production on non DE orgs) and not even expose the force.com domain name.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to change a domain-name on an existing site? Then AFAIK you have bad luck: domain names cannot be changed once they are set.

Answer (score 2):

Domain Names cannot be changed once you have setup. You need to raise a case to the salesforce and fix it and it takes a long time.You can have a change your domain name in the production.